# Sorting array results from Google Webmaster Tools API

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, foreach

I'm working on Google Webmaster Tools API, and getting results from the system in a multidimensional array. There is no sorting parameter available for Webmaster Tools API, and I can't get the batch query working due to lack of examples or documentation.

I'm running two queries side by side with different date ranges, and the problem is that the default sort (which isn't modifiable) is by 'clicks' descending. This means that the two independent results ordering don't match. I'm running a compare on both columns but only matching those that are in the same 'position' in the list.

```
    $qsearch = $searchanalytics->query($siteUrl, $request);
    $qsearch2 = $searchanalytics->query($siteUrl, $request2);
    $rows = $qsearch->getRows();
    $rows2 = $qsearch2->getRows();

    foreach ($rows as $i => $t) { $t2 = $rows2[$i];
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="clicks" width="150px" align="center">'.$t['clicks'].'</td>';
    echo '<td class="impressions width="120px" align="center">'.$t['impressions'].'</td>';
    echo '<td class="impressions2" width="120px" align="center">'.$t2['impressions'].'</td>';
    echo '<td class="ctr" width="120px" align="center">'.round($t['ctr'],2).'</td>';
    echo '<td class="position" width="120px" align="center">'.round($t['position'],2).'</td>';
    echo '<td class="keyword" width="500px">'.$t['keys'][0].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
```

I need advice on how to resort the row and rows2 arrays based on the 'keyword' value of both queries.

Arrays I can't get my head around...

Comment: Are `$rows` and `$rows2` PHP array-structured data? If yes, then it's sortable. Can you show the result of its `print_r()`?

Comment: You have a bunch of built-in functions in PHP to sort arrays. You got [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php), [`asort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php), [`arsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php), [`krsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php), [`ksort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php), [`rsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php), [`sort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php), [`uasort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php), [`uksort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php)

Comment: [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), [`natsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php), [`natcasesort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php) and even [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php).

Comment: $rows and $rows2 are json encoded. Any of the sort functions don't work with an error.

Comment: Sorry but you said *I need advice on how to resort the row and rows2 **arrays***

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own question:

```
usort($rows, function($b, $a) { 
return $a->keys[0] > $b->keys[0] ? -1 : 1; 
});
```

Comment: Well, apparently they weren't `json_encode`d in the end heh? :)